# Acumos "Site Admin" changes with unexpected side effects

Tags: acumos

After following the AIO install procedure I logged in as admin user on the Acumos portal (https://xxxxxx:30443/#/home) and changed only the "Site Instance Name" in "Site Admin->Site Configuration". This did change the name of the site on the home page but it also resulted in that the text accompanying the "Marketplace, Onboarding, ..." options disappeared together with the text in the "Contact information" in the page footer.

See the screenshots for details related to what I did and the differences on the Acumos landing page.

***How do I get this text back (or add/change it to whatever I would like it to be)?***

**What it looked like before the "Site Instance Name Change":**

[image: What it looked like before the change]

**The change I made:**

[image: The change I made]

**What it looked like after the change:**

[image: What it looked like after the change]

Comment: What version number is shown in the page footer - 1.16.6?  I think I reproduced the problem here.  I opened Jira issue https://jira.acumos.org/browse/ACUMOS-2553

Comment: On my instance the version number is 1.16.2. Is there anyway to get the text back or is it a bug that needs to be fixed first? Where is the text stored (is it in Hippo)?

Comment: I have not figured it out yet.  You might add yourself as a watcher to the Jira issue linked above, then you'll know as soon as I do.