# Acumos model download failed

Tags: acumos

I installed Acumos using AIO *oneclick_deploy.sh docker* command. I have successfully managed to upload a sample tensorflow model and made it available in the Marketplace. When I try do download (i.e. clicking on the "Download" button) the model from the Marketplace I get only empty files. If I try to download using the "Deploy to local" option I do get the setup files (so that option seems to work). Any suggestions on how to solve the "Download" problem? I get the following error in the portel-be error log when trying the "Download" option:

org.acumos.portal.be.common.exception.AcumosServiceException: Error transferring file: Connection refused (Connection refused) from http://acutn:3\
0881/repository/acumos_model_maven/com/artifact/138c462f-8858-4c16-b53a-fa494d9af12e/model/1/model-1.proto
        at org.acumos.portal.be.service.impl.MarketPlaceCatalogServiceImpl.getPayload(MarketPlaceCatalogServiceImpl.java:1404)
        at org.acumos.portal.be.service.impl.MarketPlaceCatalogServiceImpl.getProtoUrl(MarketPlaceCatalogServiceImpl.java:1460)
        at org.acumos.portal.be.controller.MarketPlaceCatalogServiceController.fetchProtoFile(MarketPlaceCatalogServiceController.java:1160)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor394.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:\
97)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.jav\
a:849)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:760\
)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.acumos.portal.be.security.AuthenticationTokenFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationTokenFilter.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)

Comment: The portal-be acts as a proxy here, on request it contacts the local Nexus server to fetch artifacts and pumps them out to your web browser.  Does every file download fail, or only some of the files? Just to ask the obvious question, is the Nexus server docker container running?  As a test, please aim your browser at that server's URL to check its health, it has a browser/HTML interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to fix the problem. I noticed that several Acumos related Containers had stopped. The error reason for some of the containers indicated connection error to URLs including only the hostname (acutn). I added the following to /etc/network/interfaces:

*dns-search tele.no*

since this will allow for the resolving of local hostnames to include FQDN. I then restarted the stopped containers. The stopped containers now run without error and I can download files.

I do think that something should be added to the AIO scripts in order to avoid similar problems or maybe a clear warning/instruction on how to name a server could be in place.

Answer (score 0):

From the portal-be error line: "org.acumos.portal.be.common.exception.AcumosServiceException: Error transferring file: Connection refused (Connection refused) from http://acutn:3\ 0881/repository/acumos_model_maven/com/artifact/138c462f-8858-4c16-b53a-fa494d9af12e/model/1/model-1.proto"

It looks like this is a portal-be configuration issue. In particular the "http://acutn:3\ 0881/" part is not correct. But such a value for the port "3\ 0881" should have prevented the Nexus server from coming up. Please check http://acutn:30881 by curl or in your browser.

Comment: I suspect the three-backslash-eight.. sequence is just a copy-paste artifact, not a configuration-file botch.

Comment: Yes, the three-backslash-eight sequence is indeed a copy-paste artifact. It actually looks like this problem is related to the problem described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54808494/acumos-site-admin-changes-with-unexpected-side-effects. If the hostname is not a complete FQDN it looks like running the AIO script falls into all kinds of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions for oneclick_deploy.sh do indicate:

"All hostnames specified in acumos-env.sh must be DNS-resolvable on all host (entries in /etc/hosts or in an actual DNS server)"

Also to make sure that a non-DNS domain name is resolvable, the container templates add this entry to the container hosts file:

```
  hostAliases:
  - ip: "<ACUMOS_HOST>"
    hostnames:
    - "<ACUMOS_DOMAIN>"`
```

If there's some other instruction I should add, let me know.

Comment: Well, DNS-resolvable (IMO) usually means that the full name (i.e. hostname.domain) is resolvable. Local hostnames without FQDN are not meant to be resolvable. Is it even possible to add a hostname (without domain) to a DNS server? Our server (with hostname.FQDN) is of course added to our DNS server and as such we did believe that the sentence "All hostnames specified in acumos-env.sh must be DNS-resolvable on all host (entries in /etc/hosts or in an actual DNS server)" was fulfilled. In my opinion the AIO should not allow the usage of hostnames without FQDN. For us it has resulted in problems.